# How to get data from Laravel db into googlechart?

Tags: php, laravel, google-api

I want to introduce my counts into this GoogleChart. I want to count all id from table News/Opinions/Events etc.I want to be able to put numbers of all records from News/Opinions/Events etc. If in "News" table I have 10 news, i want to count them and introduce it to ['News', 'All news HERE'],

And the second, I want to add it into this code:

```
<script>
 google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['News', 'All news HERE'],
          ['Events',    No of events from db],


        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities',
          pieHole: 0.4,
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
</script>
```

Comment: you have to get the data in the controller and then pass it in to the view. print your data in the desired format, an array of string. The html and js are executed after the page is loaded

Comment: and how can I get the data in the controller ?

Comment: by using an sql query or using **eloquent model** that laravel uses. You should check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just query your database to get all counts that you needed (should be fast if you don't query many tables).

```php
public function myControllerAction() {
    $dbData = DB::selectOne('
        select
        (select count(*) from news) as News, 
        (select count(*) from events) as Events, 
        (select count(*) from someothertable) as Someotherdata 
    ');

    return view('my-view', compact('dbData'));
}
```

After this you can use **$dbData->News, $dbData->Events, $dbData->Someotherdata** and put it anywhere you like in your code.

You can even simplify your future development by using Laravel's **Collection** and generating a ready to use array for google charts:

```php
public function myControllerAction() {
    $dbData = DB::selectOne('
        select
        (select count(*) from news) as News, 
        (select count(*) from events) as Events, 
        (select count(*) from someothertable) as Someotherdata 
    ');

    $collection = new \Illuminate\Support\Collection($dbData);
    $data = $collection->flatMap(function($value, $key) {
        // We will use name of the key as the label for chart (News, Events, Someotherdata)
        return [[$key, $value]];
    })->toArray();

    return view('my-view', compact('data'));
}
```

And just use Blade's **@json** directive to render the json where you need it:

```javascript
<script>
 google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        // Here is the changed part, notice the @json($data) here
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(@json($data));

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities',
          pieHole: 0.4,
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I really can't fully understand what you are trying to do but I will show you whole concept
in `web.php` route file :

```
   Route::get('/newsCount', 'NewsController@count');
```

in `NewsController.php` controller file :

```
public function count()
    {
        $CountOfNews = News::all()->count(); // Get count of all your news
        // Now you can use one of these two ways 
        // Pass data to view way 1
        return View::make("user/NewsCount", compact('CountOfNews')); 
        // Pass data to view way 2
        return View::make("user/NewsCount")->with(array('Count'=>$CountOfNews));        
    }
```

and into your `balde.php` view file you should do like this :

```
<script>
 alert({{$CountOfNews}});
</script>
```

Comment: I used $CountOfNews = News::all()->count;  but I receive all data from database, all columns.I want to receive a number, like 5 or 10 rows.Not all data.

Comment: sorry I forget to use `()`. change `$CountOfNews = News::all()->count;` to `$CountOfNews = News::all()->count();` and you can also try `$CountOfNews = News::count(); `